# Erro NotFoundHttpException ao copiar site Laravel

Tags: laravel

Criei um site em uma máquina e funciona tudo bem.

Fiz a cópia da pasta para outro computador, instalei o Composer, digitei os comandos `composer update`, `php artisan migrate` e `php artisan app:name farmacia`. Porém ao acessar, recebo o erro

`NotFoundHttpException`

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Mas se eu acessar o link direto `localhost/farmacia/public/municipios` ele acessa de boa.

O que pode ser?

Comment: vc rodou o comando php artisan key:generate?

Comment: qual é o texto da exception?

Comment: Outro site quer dizer apenas outra pasta ou também outro servidor?

Comment: @fernandosavio foi pra outro computador

Comment: @AdemilsonSantanadaSilva o texto é `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`, rei rodar esse comando pra ver

Comment: Dá uma olhada no arquivo `.env` lá vão estar configurações específicas do servidor.

Comment: @fernandosavio aparentemente está tudo ok no arquivo `.env`

Comment: só pelo endereço já vejo problemas, está mau configurado onde a pasta `public` é o root da sua aplicação, qualquer outra configuração pode ter problemas como está tendo ... Configure a sua aplicação para iniciar o servidor Web na pasta `public` e utilize as rotas configuradas no seu sistema sem problemas a partir disso.

Comment: oi @VirgilioNovic sou novato no laravel e é a primeira vez que faço isso. nem consegui tirar a home do public (estou usando wamp no meu pc local pra testar)